# Gulp Child Process hangs

Tags: gulp

I am trying to create a gulp task that updates all the assets in my project by executing a shell script. The problem is that it executes as expected and then just hangs.

```
'use-strict';

var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util');
    exec    = require('child_process').exec;
var foreach = require('gulp-foreach');

gulp.task('update-assets', function () {
        exec('./update_assets.sh', {cwd: 'assets'}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['update-assets'], function() {
    gulp.start('update-assets');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the nature of `exec()`. What exec() does it allows the command you give it to "take over" the current process. What you can do is instead try something like `child_process.spawn` . If it is a daemon process.

Take a good look at the [Child_Process documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). I think that this should help you get a good start.

Other options that may be helpful include modifying the script to throw exit codes for Gulp to recognize, or using timeouts to know when a gulp task has terminated.

UPDATE: Alternatively, you could use this, which is what I found worked for me when running a web server. 
    `shell.exec('./update_assets.sh', {async:true} );`